# What are rule of thumb or technical standard for industrial fan?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fan

I want to design a small centrifugal fan to transport wood dust. Is there any Handbook or ISO/DIN/ASME standard for industrial fan? For example, number of blade, hub size, shaft diameter, blade thickness, shroud thickness, etc.

Comment: A google search for "fan standards" is blessed with many results. This was the top for me: https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso:5801:ed-2:v1:en

Comment: There is nothing simple about fan engineering. One of the better books is *Woods Practical Guide To Fan Engineering*, B B Daly, Published by Woods of Colchester Limited, 1978 to 1992.